# Drupal: Sub menu of main menu not showing in zen subtheme

Tags: drupal

Failed to list out sub menu items using zen subtheme.

My main menu:

```
 -> Home
   -> Product
         -> men
         -> female
   -> about
```

**MY PROBLEM:**

-> sub menu "men" and "female" are not shown

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR:**

My code in page.tpl.php

```
             <?php if ($main_menu): ?>                
                  <?php
                  // This code snippet is hard to modify. We recommend turning off the
                  // "Main menu" on your sub-theme's settings form, deleting this PHP
                  // code block, and, instead, using the "Menu block" module.
                  // @see https://drupal.org/project/menu_block
                  print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
                    'links' => $main_menu,
                    'attributes' => array(
                      'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix'),
                    ),
                    'heading' => array(
                      'text' => t('Main menu'),
                      'level' => 'h2',
                      'class' => array('element-invisible'),
                    ),
                  )); ?>                
              <?php endif; ?>

              <?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>
```

I have **checked** "*Show as expanded*" for **product** menu item in main menu also.

Please provide me solution.